# how to display real time change in stock price in ionic app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, stock, twelvedata

I have a 3rd party api https://api.twelvedata.com/time_series?symbol=TEST_SYMBOL&interval=1day&apikey=YOUR_API_KEY I have displayed stock price list in the cards. Now I have to show the real time data of each card with each sec changes how do i do that.
i have tried many ways but entire api is getting fetched instead of updating data of single card.

Comment: Please include code relating to your current attempt and its behavior

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the api provided supports websocket configuration. but if the api is loaded it does not change price i have to refresh the browser and check the price change

Comment: Please, edit the question or post as a comment, this is not an Answer

Answer (score -1):

**Does your API support WebSockets?**

**What are WebSockets?**
Websocket is a full-duplex protocol that allows real-time communication between client and web server through emitting and listening for events.

check this link for more
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

**Websockets with angular**

https://javascript-conference.com/blog/real-time-in-angular-a-journey-into-websocket-and-rxjs/